# Conditional formatting in a matrix

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, reportbuilder3.0

This is my matrix in design view

[image]

The Last column has the following expression in it.  This brings back the latest date for that particular row.

```
=Format(Max(Fields!DateTime.value),"dd/MM/yyyy  HH:mm:ss")
```

I want to colour the ones that have occurred within the last 6 weeks

```
=IIF(DateDiff(DateInterval.Day , Fields!DateTime.Value, Today()) <=42, "#f5c6c8", Nothing)
```

This brings back the following

[image]

For some reason it's working for some fields and not others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right managed to figure this out, needed to put max in my expression

```
=max(IIF(DateDiff(DateInterval.Day , Fields!DateTime.Value, Today()) <=42, "#f5c6c8", Nothing))
```